# UWP C#: Open HTML file from local disk to default browser

Tags: c#, uwp

Following code works to open an `online URL`. But it does NOT work for a web page (an `HTML file`) from `local disk`:

**Question**: It seems I'm missing something here. How can we make it for an html file from a local drive?

**NOTE**: No error is return, only the value of `success` variable is returned 
`false`. I've verified that the HTML file exist by successfully opening it manually.

```
async void DefaultLaunch()
{
   // The URI to launch. NOTE: It works only for online URLs, http://www.bing.com etc.
   var uriTest = new Uri(@"file:///C:/DotNET2017/Test.html");

    // Launch the URI
    try
    {
        var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uriTest);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        string st = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

**Screenshot of `uriTest` value in debug mode**:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can't use "file///..." to lunch a local file.
you should use the launch file function and since it's an .html it will open in in the browser

first Get your IStorageFile from:

[GetFileFromPathAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefrompathasync)

and then just launch your file:

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(myStorageFile)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:

> LaunchUriAsync(Uri)
>   Returns true if the default app for the URI scheme was launched; false otherwise.

So there must be an app registered to handle the scheme. There is no app in the system that is registered to handle the file: scheme, it is rather handled by the system itself which is not the app. So if you take this into account it returns false as expected.

You should rather use `Launcher.LaunchFileAsync` method. But please note that if you don't define the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability you will not be able to get the `StorageFile` out of the arbitrary path to send as the parameter for that method.